# load page with pushViewController on tabbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have UIViewController with tabbar botton, and navigation bar and navigation item,
when I press on my button in navigation Item I want to load a view, I don't know how to load this view on tabbar,

would you please help me,thanks in advance!

Comment: share more code, self.navigationController might be nil, looks like you have UIViewControllers (_viewCtrl1,_viewCtrl2,_viewCtrl3)..but not UINavigationController?

Comment: @shahid-rasheed it's not working with NSNotification centre, it 's work normally when I use this code but I want to use NSNotificationCenter

Comment: add breakpoint and check if infoPage: methods even gets called by notification? Make sure UIViewControoler (observer) should be in memory when you post your notification.

Answer (score 0):

```
      -(IBAction) infoPage:(id)sender
      {

       InfoCtrol *i = [[InfoCtrol alloc] initWithNibName:@"InfoCtrol" bundle:nil]; 
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:i animated:YES];

      }
```

This will load the InfoCtrol controller and set the Touch UpInside Event in xib to the infoPage method

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to hide the tab bar when you push new controller in navigation?

If true. There is a property hidesBottomBarWhenPushed in the UIViewController class.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Instead of adding ViewController to TabbarController, add NavigationControllers.
// Eg.

UINavigationController *NavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_viewCtrl1];
[watchListNavController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

_tabC = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
_tabCt.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:NavController,_viewCtrl2,_viewCtrl3, nil];

// Now you can use Push and Pop In your _viewCtrl1. 
// Do same with all the viewController
```